# How to show [a,b) is not open with respect to Euclidean topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, advice

Show that, if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$, then $[a,b)$ is not open set.

I am using Topology Without Tears by Sydney Morris

**My thoughts on it**

Observe  $a\in [a,b)$.

Suppose that there exists $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $c\leq d$ $a\in(c,d)\subseteq[a,b)$

$a\in(c,d)$ implies $c\leq a < d$ and $c\leq 0.5(a+c) < c < b$.

So $0.5(a+c)\notin [a,b)$ and $0.5(a+c)\in (c,d)$.

So $[a,b)\not\subseteq (c,d)$. Contradiction.

So $[a,b)$ is not open.

Basically I am tweaking Morris’s argument.

It is obviously not open since it does not contain the point $b$

Let $I_{n} = [a,b-1/n) \bigcup_{n\in N} I_n = [a,b)$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $a \in (c, d)$ implies $c<a<d$, so $c \notin [a,b)$.

Comment: What do you mean by the sentence "It is obviously not open since it does not contain the point $b$"? Are you saying that $[a,b)$ is (obviously) not open because $b\not\in[a,b)$?

Comment: It might be a good idea to say "is not open *with respect to the Euclidean metric*", but perhaps I'm being overly pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the exact right idea!

$[a,b)$ is open if and only if each $x \in [a,b)$ has an open interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subseteq [a,b)$. So to show that $[a,b)$ *isn't* open, we must find a point $x$ for which that condition fails.

You're exactly right to think $a$ is a good choice of point. We want to show that no matter how small an $\epsilon$ we choose, $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \not \subseteq [a,b)$.

Of course, this is easy! Since $a - \frac{\epsilon}{2} \in (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$, and yet $a-\frac{\epsilon}{2} \not \in [a,b)$.

So $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \not \subseteq [a,b)$. As needed.

---

As a remark, I'm not sure what you mean by "It is obviously no open since it does not contain the point b". Perhaps this was a typo and you meant it is obviously not *closed* since it doesn't contain $b$, and this would be true. After all, $b$ is in the closure of $[a,b)$ (do you see why?).

As you saw from the argument above (and the argument you outlined), the relevant point for showing $[a,b)$ is not open is $a$, not $b$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

*I shall prove it for the case of $(0,1]$ and you shall prove this for $(\alpha, \beta]$ using a similar argument*.

Consider the interval $(0,1]$, we claim that such set is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ since
$1$ is not an interior point of $(0,1]$. To see this, notice that $\forall \varepsilon>0$, the neighbourhood $(1-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon) \nsubseteq(0,1]$ . For instance :
$$1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \in(1-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon)$$
However :
$$1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \notin(0,1]$$

Comment: You should probably change your opening sentence to reference $(0, 1]$ and not $[0, 1)$.

Comment: I apologize I don't seem to understand what you mean, if you wish you can edit my post and I would be happy to accept.  @BrianTung

Comment: I just mean in most of your post, you're proving something about the interval $(0, 1]$, but you start your answer by saying you're going to prove it for $[0, 1)$.  If it's still unclear, maybe I misunderstand what you're doing.

Comment: Ohh I am sorry I did not see that, thank you very much!

Comment: Epsilon proofs haven’t been used in the text yet.

Comment: What I presented is a strategy for a rigorous proof.